# Why my dovecot can't receive email sent by others?

Tags: dovecot

postfix and dovecot was installed on my vps--centos7.

I can send email to others ,why can't receive email sent by others?

No problem for ports.

```
netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

To telnet my vps.

```
telnet xxxxxxx  110
Trying xxxxxxxx...
Connected to xxxxxx
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It is no use to close firewall with  `systemctl stop firewalld`.

How to check the bug for my dovecot?
1. doveconf -n

```
 # 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
 # OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab123.3 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)  
disable_plaintext_auth = no
first_valid_uid = 1000
listen = *
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
}
ssl = required
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

2. postconf -n

   alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
   alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
   broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
   command_directory = /usr/sbin
   config_directory = /etc/postfix
   daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
   data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
   debug_peer_level = 2
   debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
   home_mailbox = Maildir/
   html_directory = no
   inet_interfaces = all
   inet_protocols = all
   local_recipient_maps =
   mail_owner = postfix
   mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
   manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
   mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
   mydomain =   xxxx
   myhostname = xxxx
   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
   myorigin = $mydomain
   newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
   queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
   readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
   relay_domains = $mydestination
   sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
   sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
   setgid_group = postdrop
   smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
   smtpd_recipient_restrictions =    permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,permit_mynetworks
   smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
   smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
   unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
3. telnet xxxx  25

   Trying xxxx
   Connected to xxxxxx
   Escape character is '^]'.
   220 xxxxxx ESMTP Postfix

Comment: Please provide information on your Dovecot and MDA (probably Postfix) configuration: `doveconf -n`, `postconf -n`. Can you connect to your server from outside on port 25?

Comment: Do you have an MX record in DNS for your domain?

Comment: Please post __logs__ from Postfix and Dovecot of what happens when you don't receive a message.  Your question can't be answered without these logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
dig domain.tld in MX
```

give you a response that shows something like:

```
domain.tld.  86400 IN MX 10 mail.domain.tld.
```

If not, you will need to add an MX record in DNS like this:

```
owner-name           ttl  class   rr  pref name
example.com.         3w   IN      MX  10   mail.example.com.
```

Here is a decent explanation and the source of the above example:

[Mail Exchange Record (MX) on zytrax.com](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/mx.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
dig  mydomain.com in MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.com        285 IN  SOA 


dig  mail.mydomain.com  in MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.mydomain.com.  300 IN  MX  10 mydomain.com
```

The mydomain.com was not added a MX record, mail.mydomain.com  added a MX record.

To add an MX record in DNS for mydomain.com instead of mail.mydomain.com in my domainname server.

```
owner-name           ttl  class   rr  pref name
mydomain.com         3w   IN      MX  10   mydomain.com
```

Comment: Please don't add an answer that repeats what someone else has suggested. Instead, accept their answer. If you made slight adjustments you can add those as comments under their answer.